Without Repetition for Wood Texture
Trying to create a texture that should be generated like wood, but not repetition tile. This is the picture I used as a texture. 
Here is an image from Cycle Render.

Here is my Geo Node.

For example, Blender Guru used Shader Nodes to generate the image in tile without repetition, however, I noticed he used the oldest Version 2.82 and I have version 4.2.
https://youtu.be/-VgtSL5ZpYc?si=U2l9yOUXJD2WTVV-

a quick way would be to use your image as stencil to paint on the surface of your object
